# jQueryプラグイン作成時の画像の場所

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryプラグインを作ったのですが、読み込む必要がある画像の配置場所に迷っています。
普通にフォルダに配置するものでしょうか？
読み込む画像は一つなのでいっそBase64でエンコードして埋め込んでしまおうかとも思ったのですが、それも微妙かな、と。

Answer (score 1):

画像の内容によりけりですが、ある程度の大きさの画像をdataurlで持つとブラウザによって出たり出なかったりなどつまらないことで頭を悩ませる必要があり、いわゆるイメージファイルをdataurlに入れる構造のプラグインにするのはあまりお勧めできない気がします。
文字の背景にボーダー柄を設定したい、と言った場合にはCanvasに1ピクセルづつ色を付けてbase64に変換し、cssで引き延ばすようにしています。